# Log only 4xx and 5xx HTTP response errors in HAPROXY 2.1

Tags: linux, logging, configuration, load-balancing, haproxy

In HaProxy 2.1 version, I am trying to log only 4xx and 5xx errors.

Here's snippet of config file:

```
global
  log stdout local0

defaults
  log global
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option dontlog-normal
  mode http
  .
  .
```

When I use option dontlog-normal, it just logs 5xx errors and specific 403 errors restricted by ACL.
With option log-separate-errors, it again just logs 5xx errors. But both option doesn't log any 404 and other 4x errors in the logs.

Is there any way to include both 5xx and 4xx in a dedicated error logfile ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `http-response set-log-level err if { status 400:499 }` (see [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20set-log-level)) should do for client errors the equivalent of what `option log-separate-errors` does for server/connection errors.

Comment: Changing log level to err works except for 403 code. But along with option log-separate-errors this 403 and other 5xx is also taken care of.